# C++ Writing Own Input Manipulator

Tags: c++

I have a data text file which contains this

```
Map2D, [3, 2]
Dot3D, [25, -69, -33], [-2, -41, 58]
Map3D, [6, 9, -50]
Map2D, [3, 2]
Dot3D, [7, -12, 3], [9, 13, 68]
Map3D, [6, 9, 5]
Map2D, [3, 2]
Dot3D, [70, -120, -3], [-29, 1, 268]
Dot3D, [7, 12, 3], [-9, 13, 68]
Map3D, [1, 3, 8]
Dot2D, [5, 7], [3, 8]
```

Basically the text file first data is the class name which i got 4 class

```
Map2D
Map3D
Dot2D
Dot3D
```

I was trying to write my own file manipulator so that my program can extract the data above and overload the extraction operator >> for each of the 4 class and then storing it into relevant object.

I was thinking of using vector, map, set or list to store . but for this how do i achieve what i want to do such as store into relevant object of the class.

I tried googling around on how to create my own file manipulator, but will be good if someone could show me some sample code and i can compile and execute it maybe in a test file then observe the output myself. I would like to use iomanip to do a overload on the >> operator

I am sorry for all the trouble caused. Also can i don't use array to achieve the following storing of data.

I have to use manipulator because i need create something like

I need to do something like

```
cout << "Input File Name";
cin >> readFile;
```

and perform all the data reading & object creation

then it will read the records line by line, then create the class and also the data in it.

**Thanks for all your help!**

Comment: The part I'm not getting is why you need to write a manipulator. Manipulators are normally used to modify stream state. As far as I can see all you need to do is overload `operator>>` for each of your four classes. The answer to the second question might be as simple as using polymorphism.

Comment: @john , thanks for helping. I understand but seriously i try google around and to no chance i understand how to do it. I am good with other programing language, but this manipulator thing, can you give me some sample codes like how can i get this done with 1 of the class. I know i should not ask it this way. But It will really be GREATLY apperciated. Thanks again!

Comment: What you seem to need is not a file manipulator but a simple parser. I suggest you simply have a parser object which reads your file one line at a time, parses the first word, and instantiates an object of the appropriate class based on the first word. A simple parser like that would also make it much easier to do error trapping if the syntax of your data file is not what you expect.

Comment: @Fred i need to do data reading then perform all the object creation

Answer (score 1):

This is a very typical example of the abstract factory pattern.

You wouldn't use iomanip to do this. Read the first word, then find the appropriate handler and invoke it to read (parse) the rest of the line and create the appropriate object.

The objects themselves do not need to be covariant, the factory used to create them should be.

Of course if you want to store them all in a collection you will have to work out how you want to manage that.

And if you read in a "heading" that you don't know, you will of course fail your stream.

Comment: If i want to use it with iomanip, is it still possible to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

you can use The most obvious form of iterator is a pointer: A pointer can point to elements in an array, and can iterate through them using the increment operator (++). But other forms of iterators exist. For example, each container type (such as a vector) has a specific iterator type designed to iterate through its elements in an efficient way.

Comment: I was thinking of using map or set or list other than vector. but the problem is how to get started doing this manipulator is really hard.

Comment: why to use the manipulator use just the vector it is a templat and using it is very simple all you need is to understand to iterator idea and is better to extract any imformation from the vector then to create a manipulator

Comment: I need to do something like cout << "Input File Name"; cin >> readFile; and perform all the data reading & object creation